# What's wrong with my merge sort implementation in Perl?

Tags: perl, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I'm trying to write a merge sorting algorithm in Perl and I've attempted to copy the [pseudo code from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

So this is what I have:

```
sub sort_by_date {
    my $self        = shift;
    my $collection  = shift;

    print STDERR "\$collection = ";
    print STDERR Dumper $collection;

    if ( @$collection <= 1 ) {
        return $collection;
    }

    my ( $left, $right, $result );

    my $middle = ( @$collection / 2 ) - 1;

    my $x = 0;
    for ( $x; $x <= $middle; $x++ ) {
        push( @$left,$collection->[$x] );
    }

    $x = $middle + 1;
    for ( $x; $x < @$collection; $x++  ) {
        push( @$right,$collection->[$x] );
    }

    $left = $self->sort_by_date( $left );
    $right = $self->sort_by_date( $right );

    print STDERR '$left = ';
    print STDERR Dumper $left;
    print STDERR '$right = ';
    print STDERR Dumper $right;

    print STDERR '$self->{\'files\'}{$left->[@$left-1]} = ';
    print STDERR Dumper $self->{'files'}{$left->[@$left-1]};
    print STDERR '$self->{\'files\'}{$right->[0]} = ';
    print STDERR Dumper $self->{'files'}{$right->[0]};

    if ( $self->{'files'}{$left->[@$left-1]}{'modified'} > $self->{'files'}{$right->[0]}{'modified'} ) {
        $result = $self->merge_sort( $left,$right );
    }
    else {
        $result = [ @$left, @$right ];
    }

    return $result;
}

## We're merge sorting two lists together
sub merge_sort {
    my $self  = shift;
    my $left  = shift;
    my $right = shift;

    my @result;

    while ( @$left > 0 && @$right > 0 ) {
        if ( $self->{'files'}{$left->[0]}{'modified'} <= $self->{'files'}{$right->[0]}{'modified'} ) {
            push( @result,$left->[0] );
            shift( @$left );
        }
        else {
            push( @result,$right->[0] );
            shift( @$right );
        }
    }

    print STDERR "\@$left = @$left\n";
    print STDERR "\@$right = @$right\n";

    if ( @$left > 0 ) {
        push( @result,@$left );
    }
    else {
        push( @result,@$right );
    }

    print STDERR "\@result = @result\n";

    return @result;
}
```

The error I'm getting + the output from my debugging print statements is as follows:

```
$collection = $VAR1 = [
      'dev/css/test.css',
      'dev/scripts/out.tmp',
      'dev/scripts/taxonomy.csv',
      'dev/scripts/wiki.cgi',
      'dev/scripts/wiki.cgi.back',
      'dev/templates/convert-wiki.tpl',
      'dev/templates/includes/._menu.tpl',
      'dev/templates/test.tpl'
    ];
$collection = $VAR1 = [
      'dev/css/test.css',
      'dev/scripts/out.tmp',
      'dev/scripts/taxonomy.csv',
      'dev/scripts/wiki.cgi'
    ];
$collection = $VAR1 = [
      'dev/css/test.css',
      'dev/scripts/out.tmp'
    ];
$collection = $VAR1 = [
      'dev/css/test.css'
    ];
$collection = $VAR1 = [
      'dev/scripts/out.tmp'
    ];
$left = $VAR1 = [
      'dev/css/test.css'
    ];
$right = $VAR1 = [
      'dev/scripts/out.tmp'
    ];
$self->{'files'}{$left->[@$left-1]} = $VAR1 = {
      'type' => 'file',
      'modified' => '0.764699074074074'
    };
$self->{'files'}{$right->[0]} = $VAR1 = {
      'type' => 'file',
      'modified' => '340.851956018519'
    };
$collection = $VAR1 = [
      'dev/scripts/taxonomy.csv',
      'dev/scripts/wiki.cgi'
    ];
$collection = $VAR1 = [
      'dev/scripts/taxonomy.csv'
    ];
$collection = $VAR1 = [
      'dev/scripts/wiki.cgi'
    ];
$left = $VAR1 = [
      'dev/scripts/taxonomy.csv'
    ];
$right = $VAR1 = [
      'dev/scripts/wiki.cgi'
    ];
$self->{'files'}{$left->[@$left-1]} = $VAR1 = {
      'type' => 'file',
      'modified' => '255.836377314815'
    };
$self->{'files'}{$right->[0]} = $VAR1 = {
      'type' => 'file',
      'modified' => '248.799166666667'
    };
@ARRAY(0x8226b2c) = dev/scripts/taxonomy.csv
@ARRAY(0x8f95178) = 
@result = dev/scripts/wiki.cgi dev/scripts/taxonomy.csv
$left = $VAR1 = [
      'dev/css/test.css',
      'dev/scripts/out.tmp'
    ];
$right = $VAR1 = 2;
$self->{'files'}{$left->[@$left-1]} = $VAR1 = {
      'type' => 'file',
      'modified' => '340.851956018519'
    };
$self->{'files'}{$right->[0]} = [Tue Sep 22 13:47:19 2009] [error] [Tue Sep 22 13:47:19 2009] null: Can't use string ("2") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at ../lib/Master/ProductVersion.pm line 690.\n
```

Now the added complexity you see in the code is that for each item in the $collection array_ref passed in there is also a hash entry for that item containing item => { type => 'file', modified => 'date-last-modified' } and I'm trying to sort on the date last modified of each file.

My brain just basically can't cope with recursion and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong - it's probably obvious and/or horrendously wrong.  Any help would be much appreciated... or I'm rewriting as insertion sort!

Thanks

Comment: Providing the data you are using might help.

Comment: Some questions: (1) Why is this sort taking the `$self`?  (2) How on earth is the data built up into the structure?  (3) Why isn't your function more nearly modelled on 'each item in the array to be sorted has all the information needed associated with it'?  Poking at '$self' in order to find the time attribute for an item in the collection being sorted is...kinda bizarre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you not using the [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) function?

```
my @sorted = sort { $a->{modified} <=> $b->{modified} } @unsorted;
```

Just for the record, here is an inefficient implementation of merge sort in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub merge {
    my ($cmp, $left, $right) = @_;
    my @merged;

    while (@$left && @$right) {
        if ($cmp->($left->[0], $right->[0]) <= 0) {
            push @merged, shift @$left;
        } else {
            push @merged, shift @$right;
        }
    }
    if (@$left) {
        push @merged, @$left;
    } else {
        push @merged, @$right;
    }
    return @merged;
}

sub merge_sort {
    my ($cmp, $array) = @_;

    return @$array if @$array <= 1;

    my $mid = @$array/2 - 1;

    my @left  = merge_sort($cmp, [@{$array}[0 .. $mid]]);
    my @right = merge_sort($cmp, [@{$array}[$mid+1 .. $#{$array}]]);

    if ($left[-1] > $right[0]) {
        @left = merge $cmp, \@left, \@right;
    } else {
        push @left, @right;
    }
    return @left;    
}

my $cmp = sub {
    my ($x, $y) = @_;
    return $x <=> $y;
};

print join(", ", merge_sort $cmp, [qw/1 3 4 2 5 4 7 8 1/]), "\n";
```

Comment: yes I have just also been recommended that in IRC so I will.  Thanks

Comment: If you really want mergesort (and not quicksort) you can force it by saying `use sort '_mergesort'`

Comment: Yeah, but the only reason to do that is if you know in advance that the data is likely to be pathological for quicksort.  There are valid reasons to use a custom built version of mergesort (e.g. low memory systems that need to use files instead of memory).  Of course, there are modules in CPAN that already do most of the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: A good quicksort implementation, like Perl's, avoids most of the pathological cases.